I am trying to run a code for 3D Unet semantic image segmentation, but whenever I try to fit the model I get an error
My train image and mask are in size 256x256x256 and a break them in into patches 64x64x64 for training.
This the parts of the codes that were fine, and run perfectly
!pip install tensorflow
!pip install classification-models-3D
!pip install efficientnet-3D
!pip install segmentation-models-3D
!pip install patchify

import tensorflow as tf
import keras
print(tf.__version__)
print(keras.__version__)

import segmentation_models_3D as sm
from skimage import io
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

image = io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/SRP/SampleA_256x3_#3.tif')
img_patches = patchify(image, (64, 64, 64), step=64)  #Step=64 for 64 patches means no overlap

mask = io.imread('/content/drive/MyDrive/SRP/SampleA_256x3_#3_segmented.tif')
mask_patches = patchify(mask, (64, 64, 64), step=64)  

input_img = np.reshape(img_patches, (-1, img_patches.shape[3], img_patches.shape[4], img_patches.shape[5]))
input_mask = np.reshape(mask_patches, (-1, mask_patches.shape[3], mask_patches.shape[4], mask_patches.shape[5]))

print(input_img.shape)  # n_patches, x, y, z

n_classes=3

#Convert grey image to 3 channels by copying channel 3 times.
#We do this as our unet model expects 3 channel input. 

train_img = np.stack((input_img,)*3, axis=-1)
train_mask = np.expand_dims(input_mask, axis=4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_img, train_mask, test_size=0.10, random_state=0)

# Loss Function and coefficients to be used during training:
def dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred):
    smoothing_factor = 1
    flat_y_true = K.flatten(y_true)
    flat_y_pred = K.flatten(y_pred)
    return (2. * K.sum(flat_y_true * flat_y_pred) + smoothing_factor) / (K.sum(flat_y_true) + K.sum(flat_y_pred) + smoothing_factor)

def dice_coefficient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - dice_coefficient(y_true, y_pred)

#Define parameters for our model.

encoder_weights = 'imagenet'
BACKBONE = 'vgg16'  #Try vgg16, efficientnetb7, inceptionv3, resnet50
activation = 'softmax'
patch_size = 64
n_classes = 3
channels=3

LR = 0.0001
optim = keras.optimizers.Adam(LR)

# Segmentation models losses can be combined together by '+' and scaled by integer or float factor
# set class weights for dice_loss (car: 1.; pedestrian: 2.; background: 0.5;)
dice_loss = sm.losses.DiceLoss(class_weights=np.array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])) 
focal_loss = sm.losses.CategoricalFocalLoss()
total_loss = dice_loss + (1 * focal_loss)

# actulally total_loss can be imported directly from library, above example just show you how to manipulate with losses
# total_loss = sm.losses.binary_focal_dice_loss # or sm.losses.categorical_focal_dice_loss 

metrics = [sm.metrics.IOUScore(threshold=0.5), sm.metrics.FScore(threshold=0.5)]

preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)

#Preprocess input data - otherwise you end up with garbage resutls 
# and potentially model that does not converge.
X_train_prep = preprocess_input(X_train)
X_test_prep = preprocess_input(X_test)

#Define the model. Here we use Unet but we can also use other model architectures from the library.
model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, classes=n_classes, 
                input_shape=(patch_size, patch_size, patch_size, channels), 
                encoder_weights=encoder_weights,
                activation=activation)

model.compile(optimizer = optim, loss=total_loss, metrics=metrics)
print(model.summary())
     


but whenever I am trying to run the following part :
#Fit the model
history=model.fit(X_train_prep, 
          y_train,
          batch_size=4, 
          epochs=50,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_test_prep, y_test))

I get this error : TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 2>()
1 #Fit the model
----> 2 history=model.fit(X_train_prep,
3           y_train,
4           batch_size=4,
5           epochs=50,
4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models_3D/base/functional.py in tf__f_score(gt, pr, beta, class_weights, class_indexes, smooth, per_image, threshold, **kwargs)
45                 pr = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(round_if_needed), (ag__.ld(pr), ag__.ld(threshold)), dict(**ag__.ld(kwargs)), fscope)
46                 axes = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(get_reduce_axes), (ag__.ld(per_image),), dict(**ag__.ld(kwargs)), fscope)
---> 47                 tp = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(backend).sum, (ag__.ld(gt) * ag__.ld(pr),), dict(axis=ag__.ld(axes)), fscope)
48                 fp = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(backend).sum, (ag__.ld(pr),), dict(axis=ag__.ld(axes)), fscope) - ag__.ld(tp)
49                 fn = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(backend).sum, (ag__.ld(gt),), dict(axis=ag__.ld(axes)), fscope) - ag__.ld(tp)
TypeError: in user code:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1338, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models_3D/base/objects.py", line 114, in __call__  *
    return self.l1(gt, pr) + self.l2(gt, pr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models_3D/losses.py", line 104, in __call__  *
    **self.submodules
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/segmentation_models_3D/base/functional.py", line 145, in f_score  *
    tp = backend.sum(gt * pr, axis=axes)

please help me figure out what is wrong here.
